# Convert Text Input String to SQL Datetime

Tags: javascript

I'm using a DateTime Picker so that the info is presented in a readable format for the user, ie:

`01/21/2014 10:45 PM`

The input has a class of .start so when I get the value upon form submission:

`$('.start').val();`

I get a string: `"01/21/2014 10:45 PM"`

I'm trying to write a JS function that will convert that to a Datetime format before posting it to my database, ie:

`2014-01-17 22:45:00`

Comment: You can split the string on non-digit and non-alpha characters, adjust values that need it (e.g. hrs and am/pm), then format the string. Have a go, post your code, you'll get help. :-)

Comment: r u using any server side script like php? if yes you can convert it timestamp before submit in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple function like:

```
function stringToISOString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/[\/ :]/g);
  var t = b[b.length - 1].toLowerCase() == 'am'? 0 : 12;

  return b[2] + '-' + b[0] + '-' + b[1] + ' ' + (+b[3] + t) + ':' + b[4] + ':00';
}

console.log(stringToISOString('01/21/2014 10:45 PM')); //2014-01-17 22:45:00
```

however that assumes the minutes are always zero. You can test for that and set an approriate value if you wish, e.g.

```
function stringToISOString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/[\/ :]/g);
  var t = b[b.length - 1].toLowerCase() == 'am'? 0 : 12;

  // deal with minutes
  var mins = /^\d+$/.test(b[5])? b[5] : '00';

  return b[2] + '-' + b[0] + '-' + b[1] + ' ' + (+b[3] + t) + ':' + b[4] + ':' + mins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CFkQFjAF&url=http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/source.html&ei=vhHeUubTJ4OMrQfewoDYDA&usg=AFQjCNFVZk4ICMyE7-ud_jCx8OsFb11Zig&bvm=bv.59568121,d.bmk) - there is a function called `getdatefromformat()` which you can use for your date formatting.